# Animate view when model changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-animation

I am using AngularJS v1.2.16, got simple animations like fadeIn working with `ng-show` using the class conventions, but also want to fadeIn (or blink) a given div when a given object of the model changes (info of this object is display inside that div).

Note that my code uses `$scope.$apply();` as the source of the change is not AngularJS.

```
$scope.someObject = newData; // Update of the model.
$scope.$apply(); // Force changes.
```

Maybe there is a way to force the animation before or after the apply or should this be done in a directive ? Finding information on this is quite confusing due to the changes that occurred on the animation system.